# Bad php scripts bringing server to a stand still

Tags: php, lamp

I have a pretty standard LAMP setup on my Debian VPS. The VPS has 512MB of ram, and I've assigned 128MB in my php.ini for php.

If I create a script with an infinite loop in it the VPS pretty much comes to a standstill (SSH stops being responsive etc..)

I was wondering if there's a way to lower PHP's priority or something like that so that bad scripts can't interfere too much with the server.

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have two options here, depending on how you run this.  One solution is to limit the runtime of PHP scripts--that is, you can have a PHP script terminate automatically based on its actual run time.

If you're running this from a web server (Apache, Lighttpd, etc.), you can use the [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) parameter.  By default, this is 30 seconds.  If you're running this from the CLI, use the [set_time_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function.

Another solution is to use something such as `monit` to monitor the load and CPU usage of the PHP process and kill it if it gets to a specified level.

Hope this helps; although it might be a good idea to eliminate these kinds of logic errors from your scripts entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Use `nice` or `renice` on the webserver process if PHP is running as a module (e.g. mod_php). This will allow PHP to use more resources when they are available, but will prioritize other processes which may need them.

I should add that this is only for Linux, and maybe UNIX.